# How to use CDN hosted highlight.js using Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax-highlighting, highlight.js

Where do I place the following links to get highlight.js to work on my Rails application (https://highlightjs.org/download/)?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.4/highlight.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: on app/views/layouts/application.html

Comment: yep, in the middle of head tags

Comment: If you hit answer I will upvote. I can't believe it was so easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on `app/views/layouts/application.html`

In the middle of head tags.

Sometimes is hard to identify something in the many things you need to learn about Rails.